# Why it is possible to specify a value comparer for ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>?

Tags: c#, .net, immutability, .net-core, dictionary

What is the intended usage of the  [ImmutableDictionary<TKey,TValue>.ValueComparer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2.valuecomparer?view=net-5.0) property?

Why is it useful being able to compare dictionary values by using a specified equality semantic?

I totally understand the necessity of being able to compare dictionary keys by using a specified equality semantic, but I can't get the point for value comparison. Why the immutable dictionary creator should be able to specify the intended semantic for value comparison ? Can you please show me a use case where it is useful ?

Interestingly enough, by checking at the Microsoft documentation, it seems that the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class does **not** have a similar property. The only available comparer on the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class is [the one meant to compare the keys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.comparer?view=net-5.0).

I'm totally sure that the public API of the `ImmutableDictionary<TKey,TValue>` class has been carefully designed, so I would like to understand what I'm missing about the need for value comparison in a dictionary.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/43809.

Comment: @Robert Harvey thanks for the link it is very useful. It points out that controlling the semantic used to compare values is **really** important in order to determine the behavior of the `SetItem` method.

Comment: There is no equivalent of the `SetItem` method in the public API of the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class, so in that case give the caller the possibility to customize the value comparison semantic is far less relevant.

Answer (score 3):

I think the question should not be why `ImmutableDictionary<TKey,TValue>` allows to specify a comparer for values - the question should be why `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not.

Both classes are general purpose containers for key-value pairs, with methods `ContainsKey` and `ContainsValue`. Both containers allow to specify an individual comparer for keys which is used in `ContainsKey`. So it is quite natural to assume - at least for reasons of symmetry - that specifying such a comparer for values should be possible as well.  For  `ImmutableDictionary<...>`, the designers obviously decided to do so, for `Dictionary<...>`, the designers did not, which seems to be odd, at least.

I can only speculate why `Dictionary<...>` is designed in such an unsymmetric way. My best guess is at the time when `Dictionary<...>` was introduced (14 years ago, in 2006, .Net Fw 2.0) "time-to-market" was more important than making the API more elegant by keeping these details symmetric. Maybe the designers later on decided not to change the public interface of the `Dictionary<...>` class, for not risking to add any breaking changes afterwards. I can imagine the designers of `ImmutableDictionary<...>` learned from the unsymmetric design of `Dictionary<...>` and decided to fix it for this new class (which is AFAIK from this year, 2020).

For a canonical answer, you would have to ask the designers at Microsoft by themselves.

Comment: I tend to forget the existence of `ContainsValue` simply because I rarely use that method. Most of time I'm more interested in `ContainsKey`. That said the symmetry that you pointed out totally makes sense. The documentation for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` states that the default equality comparer is always used for values (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containsvalue?view=net-5.0#remarks)

Comment: Viceversa, in the case of `ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>` the method `ContainsValue` is implemented by using the value comparer provided when the immutable dictionary is created from the immutable dictionary builder. So, in the case of `ImutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>` the creator has full control over the value comparison semantic.

Comment: I think that the APIs are different due to the interesting behavior pointed out in the link added as a comment to my question by Robert Harvey. In the case of `ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>` the value semantic is relevant for the behavior of the `SetItem` method, in order to decide whether or not returning a new instance of the dictionary. This is probably the most relevant underlying cause of the different APIs.

Comment: See here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2.setitem?view=net-5.0 for the details on the behavior of the `SetItem` method.

Comment: Anyway, I agree that the Dictionary<TKey, TValue> should allow the caller to decide how to compare values, in order to control the semantic of the `ContainsValue` method.

Answer (score 1):

As always the source code can give you some insight.

As Doc Brown has already mentioned the primary goal of the `ValueComparer` is to be able to implement `ContainsValue`.

If we look at the [.NET Core implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable) of the `ImmutableDictionary` then you can see that the implementation has split into many files:

- ImmutableDictionary_2.Builder.cs
- ImmutableDictionary_2.Comparers.cs
- ImmutableDictionary_2.Enumerator.cs
- ImmutableDictionary_2.HashBucket.cs
- ImmutableDictionary_2.MutationInput.cs
- ImmutableDictionary_2.MutationResult.cs
- ImmutableDictionary_2.cs

From our perspective the last file is the interesting one because it contains the `ContainsValue` [method](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableDictionary_2.cs#L481):

```cs
public bool ContainsValue(TValue value)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item in this)
    {
        if (this.ValueComparer.Equals(value, item.Value))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But when you take a look at the [mono implementation](https://github.com/mono/ImmutableCollections/blob/master/System.Collections.Immutable/System.Collections.Immutable/ImmutableDictionary.cs#L120) then you can see it uses the comprarer in a slightly different way:

```cs
public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kv)
{
    var node = root.SearchNode(kv, CompareKV);
    return !node.IsEmpty && valueComparer.Equals(node.Value.Value, kv.Value);
}
```